# Winning Hand Argument

Tags: reading-hands

Our group is having a disagreement about who wins the hand in the following scenario:
Player 1: A, 5
Player 2: A, 2
Board has A, 5, 9, 9, 3

I called the hand as follows: both Players having a pair of Aces and that Player 1 won with his two pair; Aces, 9, with a 5 kicker. 
Player 2 lost with his Aces, 9 and 2 kicker. 
Player 2 states that it should have been a split pot because the best 5 cards were A, 9 and the 5 on the board. He that Player 1's 5 in his hand did not play, as there was a 5 on the board.

Comment: Tie. Best 5 cards every time.

Comment: Player 2 is correct.  Only the best 5 cards are relevant.